# How to reset validation after submitting form?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

After a form is submitted successfully, validation message is displayed.

Browser: Mozilla Firefox

```
this.user = {
  branch: '',
  department: '',
  designation: '',
  mobile: '+91 ',
}
this.$validator.reset()
this.errors.clear();
```

The code mentioned above is used to reset form after success.

Comment: Are you using this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-validate for validation?

Comment: No, I'm using https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/issues/55), I believe the solution for you would be something like:

```js
const blankForm = {
  branch: '',
  department: '',
  designation: '',
  mobile: '+91 '
}

clearNewShow() {
  this.formValues = {...blankForm}
  this.$validator.pause()
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$validator.errors.clear()
    this.$validator.fields.items.forEach(field => field.reset())
    this.$validator.fields.items.forEach(field => this.errors.remove(field))
    this.$validator.resume()
  })
}
```